# In products list, show highest price instead of lowest

Tags: magento, magento2

So, as the tile suggests when a user goes on the products list i want magento to show the HIGHEST price and not the lowest for the products with more prices (ex. a 1liter liquor bottle costs more than a 0.5l bottle, i want to show the price of the former).

I've already found the template file that gets involved with it, which is

`/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`

and there i can see the `$block->getDisplayValue()`  which i suppose is what returns me the price of the product, the problem i have is that i can't find where this `getDisplayValue()` is and then how to override it in my template so i can get it to return the highest price.

Hope my explanation was clear, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
   go to
app/design/frontend/{{Vender_Namespace}}/{{Theme_Name}}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
    Paste this 
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
                    <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                        <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceContainer>
            <move element="category.view.container" destination="content" before="-"/>
        </body>
    </page>

and admin->configuration->catalog->Store Front->Product Listing Sort by Set price
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not answering you sooner! Currently i'm not in the office, i'll try this as soon as i get back and i'll let you know